# Adding columns to pandas dataframe based on function

Tags: pandas, zip

In extension of [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587799/creating-a-new-column-name-based-on-a-loop-variable-and-an-additional-string), which in my belief has not finished its quest by using the command `shift`. This only moves the column by row, and that is not what we want if we desire to map an entire column to another for instance.

I wish to map several columns to a new one, and add it as a column to the existing dataframe.

So the input would be something like:

```
DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)  HOUR-MST  AWS @ 50m [m/s]  AWS @ 80m [m/s]   AMPLC (2-80m)
1/1/2009  1  8.4262  9.1207  0.1354
1/1/2009  2  9.4238  9.9013  0.1312
1/1/2009  3  5.0494  5.3328  0.0892
1/1/2009  4  4.5928  4.8802  0.1014
```

Say the name of the dataframe is `wind`, then upon using the equation:
(here AWS is the wind speed)

```
wind['new_column1'] = wind['AWS @ 50m [m/s]']**3 * wind['AMPLC (2-80m)']
wind['new_column2'] = wind['AWS @ 80m [m/s]']**3 * wind['AMPLC (2-80m)']
```

And the output would be:

```
DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)  HOUR-MST  AWS @ 50m [m/s]  AWS @ 80m [m/s]   AMPLC (2-80m)   new_column1   new_column2
1/1/2009  1  8.4262  9.1207  0.1354  xxx1  xxx2
1/1/2009  2  9.4238  9.9013  0.1312  xxx1  xxx2 
1/1/2009  3  5.0494  5.3328  0.0892  xxx1  xxx2
1/1/2009  4  4.5928  4.8802  0.1014  xxx1  xxx2
```

Then I would also be using radius as another parameter - so I'd prefer to use a for loop to choose a range of numbers based out of `np.arange(10, 20, 2)` and multiplying together as coefficient.

Something of my idea would be as follows:

```
count = 0
for rad in range(rad_range):
    wind['new_column1'+count] = wind['AWS @ 50m [m/s]']**3 * wind['AMPLC (2-80m)'] * rad**2
    count += 1
```

May I get some suggestion please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Doesn't your last code work?

Comment: it worked after I enforced str(count) to the column name!